# Suggestions for readings; Elliptic curves over function fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, elliptic-curves

I would love to know some good refercences about Elliptic curves over function fields.
Especially in view with Mordell-Weil's Theorem.
I am already familiar with the main proof of Mordell's theorem in the book "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" by Silverman-Tate, thus I am already familiar with the case over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Silverman has another book, at the graduate level, called Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.

Comment: I am also already familiar with that book, but it sadly does not discuss the case over function fields

Answer (score 3):

There are fairly detailed [notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ulmer/research/papers/2011.pdf) by Douglas Ulmer available online. They cover the important case of function fields over finite fields. I couldn't tell if this is the case that interest you.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Criptography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420071467) by Lawrence, where on chapter 8 the author treats this subject.

Comment: Thank you, I also have another book with the same name by Washington. Is it the same book you are referring to?

Comment: I've studied with this book. Yes, it's Lawrence C. washington

Answer (score 0):

See the book "Lectures on the Mordell-Weil Theorem" of Jean-Pierre Serre.

Comment: Why is this a good choice?